# Retornar objeto modificado

Tags: c++

Possuo o seguinte problema,conforme o exemplo didático abaixo:

```
    #include "b.h"
    #include "c.h"
    class A
    {
        public:
           int start();
        private:            
            B b;
            C c;
            int x;      


    }

    a.cpp

    int A::start()
    {
        c = b.copy();
        x = c.d;
        return x;
    }



    #include "c.h"
    class B
    {
        private:
            C c;        
        public:
            C copy();
    }

    b.cpp

    C B::copy()
    {
        c.add(1);   
        return c;
    }


    class C
    {           
        public:
            void add(int x);
            int d;
    }

    c.cpp

    void c.add(int x)
    {
        C::d = x + 10;
        return;
    }


    main()
   {   
      A a;
      int y;

      y = a.start();

      cout << y ;

   }
```

Ao compilar o mesmo apresenta o erro ***"error: use of deleted function"***, pois ao retornar o objeto ***c*** este não existe mais.

Como posso contornar tal situação, sabendo que tenho que retornar para a classe ***A*** o objeto modificado da classe ***C*** e que a única função na classe ***C*** tem que ser obrigatoriamente do tipo void.

Já ajudaria uma forma de ler a variável **d** (membro data) da classe **C** na classe **A**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem uma quantidade imensa de erros de sintaxe aí, muito só erro de digitação. Programar não é jogar um texto qualquer e de qualquer jeito que vai funcionar. Eu fiz algumas modificações e pelo menos compilou. Não sei se faz o que espera.

```
class C {
    private:
        int d;
    public:
        void add(int x);
};

void C::add(int x) {
    d = x + 10;
    return;
}

class B {
    private:
        C c;        
    public:
        C copy();
};

C B::copy() {
    c.add(1);   
    return c;
}

class A {
    private:
        void start();
        B b;
        C c;        
};

void A::start() {
    c = b.copy();
}

int main() {}
```

Veja [funcionando (compilando e rodando) no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5YVa2e). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ppotutrq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/OOP/ChangeObject.cpp).

Comment: Realmente fui infeliz em transformar um código bem complexo, em um exemplo didático (conforme descrito), para exemplificar o erro de compilação, porém este código não compila na plataforma Linux, pois a Classe C é destruída antes da mesma passar, por isso do erro descrito. O que pretendo é receber o objeto da classe C (que foi modificado) na classe A.

Comment: Eu só posso responder o que está na pergunta e mostrei que tirando os erros de sintaxe compila. Mais do que isso eu não poderia fazer. Se tem outros problemas faça uma nova pergunta, desta vez faça um [mcve].

Comment: Fiz algumas modificações no código original. Para que eu possa ter acesso ao membro data int d da classe C a partir da classe A.

Comment: @Morse você tem que fazer outra pergunta, essa, conforme você postou, foi respondida. Veja o [tour] e o [ask].